# Can I build this special rounding function with Standard Library components?

Tags: c++

Is there, in C++ standard library, a way to obtain a `func` function with this behaviour :

- takes a double `num` as input;
- returns the highest integer **strictly** inferior to  `num`.

I emphasize *strictly*, because if we read ‘inferior or equal’ then of course the `ceil` function will do the job.

What I want is : `func(3.1)` equals 3, `func(3.9)` equals 3, but most importantly `func(4)` equals 3 as well, and not 4. Any good idea for implementation ?

Comment: `ceil(num - 1.0)` perhaps?

Comment: Amazing ! I should have thought about it, thank you !

Comment: Might not matter to you, but `double` can store integers so large (above 2^53=9,007,199,254,740,992) or small that at first only every second integer can be represented, then (as the exponent increases further) every fourth, every eighth and so on.  In this range, subtracting 1.0 may have no effect, and if you want an integer strictly inferior you could use e.g. [`nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ceil(x)-1.0` should work. When *x* is not an integer, *ceil(x)-floor(x)=1*, and when *x* is an integer, *ceil(x)=x*, then *ceil(x)-1* is what you want.